# Using closures in an array

Tags: php

I have a code similar to this:

```
$name = '_DBR'; // This comes from a function call

$this->_Inits['_DBR'] = function () { return get_library('Database')->getConnection('users', 'read'); };

$inits = $this->_Inits[$name];
$result = $inits(); // ERROR: Function name must be a string

return $result;
```

The error I get is:

```
Function name must be a string in xxxx
```

Is there any ways I could use an array to store multiple closures and is there a working way to access them?

I use PHP 5.4.3

Comment: It seems a little odd to me that you're calling the function by reference. When testing I have this warning: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference`

Comment: Yes, I removed the return by reference, editing post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine for me in php 5.3.10.

```
$m = array();
$m['fish'] = function() { print "Hello\n"; };
$f = $m['fish'];
$f();
```

Comment: Wow, on the actual code I had made a typo, that's why that it didn't work. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, use call_user_func instead.